# Nearest neighbor matching without replacement with MatchIt

Tags: r, matching

I am doing the nearest neighbour matching from the package MatchIt.
For example

```
data("lalonde")
m.out1 <- matchit(
    treat ~ age + educ, 
    data = lalonde,
    method = "nearest",
    distance = "glm",
    replace = FALSE
)
```

But this algorithm is sensitive to the order that the treated units are matched. As in
The Effect: An Introduction to Research Design and Causality, a book by Nick Huntington-Klein
[image]

I wish to see the effect of this randomness on my result. For example, without replacement, I can generate 100 different matching results and compare how different they are or derive the variation in matching results. How can I get this kind of different matching results by matchit? I tried set.seed() in R and it returns the same results.

Thank you a ton in advance.

Comment: Have you thought of reordering the original data?

Comment: @whuber Yes I tried set.seed() and slice_sample(). The result is the same.

Comment: I don't see how either of those reorder your data.  This sounds like a programming issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matching order is controlled by the `m.order` argument, as explained in the [documentation](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/matchit.html) for `matchit()`. There are four options currently available:

- `"largest"` - matches treated units with the highest propensity score first (in theory, these will be the hardest to match); this is the default for propensity score matching
- `"smallest"` - matches the treated units with the lowest propensity score first (in theory, these will be the easiest to match)
- `"data"` - matches treated units in the order they appear in the dataset; this is the default for Mahalanobis distance matching or when matching on a distance matrix
- `"random"` - matches treated units in a random order

All of these are deterministic except `"random"`, meaning you will get the same results each time you run them. With `m.order = "random"`, changing the seed should yield different results each time and you must set a seed to be able to replicate the match. Only `"data"` is affected by the order of the data, so reordering your data will not change matches using the other options.

Another option is to use `method = "optimal"`, which performs optimal matching. Optimal matching is also a deterministic algorithm that minimizes the overall within-pair distances in the full sample, not just in one pair at a time. In this way, it avoids the arbitrariness of greedy matching.

The literature has also described another method that can work well but isn't implemented in `MatchIt`, which is to match treated units with the closest control unit first. This algorithm is slower and often performs similarly to `"smallest"` anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much @Noah. One quick question, with m.order option, the matched matrix returned is still related to the 'data' right?

Comment: Yes, so it will be in the same order every time unless you manually re-shuffle the dataset. It is organized by the rownames of the dataset.

Comment: Great, thank you.